# Probability of balls in boxes

Tags: probability

If $12$ balls are thrown at random into $20$ boxes, what is the probability that no box will receive more than $1$ ball?

So my book says the answer is: $\displaystyle \frac{20!}{8!20^{12}}$

However I am having some trouble understanding this result and was hoping for some clarification.

There's a formula in my book: $\displaystyle p=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}$ so it's apparent that $n=20$ and $k=12$, but I don't understand the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Would it be clearer if you noted ${20!\over 8!}=20\cdot19\cdot18\cdot\, \cdots\,\cdot 9$?

Comment: @DavidMitra Oh! I think I get that part now...so "ball 1" had 20 choices for a box, then "ball 2" has 19 choices (because it can't go in the box ball 1 is in) etc, is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Outline:

1. Count the number of ways to throw $12$ balls into $20$ boxes
2. Count the number of ways to throw $12$ balls into $20$ boxes *with at most one ball per box*.
3. Divide the number of desired ways by the total number of ways.

### Ways to throw $12$ balls into $20$ boxes

For each of the $12$ balls, there are $20$ options of where it can be thrown.  (The first ball could be thrown into any of $20$ boxes, the second could be thrown into any of $20$ boxes, etc.)  So, there are:

$$\underbrace{20\cdot20\cdots 20}_{12\text{ times}} = 20^{12}\text{ ways}$$

...that the balls could have been thrown.

### Ways with *at most one ball per box*

- For the first ball, we have $20$ options of where to throw it (because all the boxes are empty).
- For the second ball, we can throw it in any box *except the one taken by the first ball*, so there are $19$ options for the second ball.
- For the third ball, we can't throw it in the boxes occupied by the first or second balls, so there are only $18$ options.
- $\quad\vdots$
- For the twelfth ball, we can throw it in any box *except those occupied by balls $1, 2, 3\ldots, 11$.  So, there are $9$ options for the twelfth ball.

All together, then, there are:
\begin{align*}
20\cdot 19 \cdot 18\cdots 9 &= \frac{(20\cdot 19 \cdot 18\cdots 9)\color{red}{(8\cdot 7\cdots2\cdot 1)}}{\color{red}{(8\cdot 7\cdots2\cdot 1)}}\\
&= \frac{20!}{8!}\text{ ways}
\end{align*}

### Divide to get probability

The probability (when dealing with equally likely outcomes) is the number of desired outcomes divided by the total number of outcomes.  Here, we desire *one ball per box*.  So, the probability is:
$$\frac{\frac{20!}{8!}}{20^{12}} = \frac{20!}{8!20^{12}}$$

Answer (score 4):

Each of the twelve balls can go into any box, so the total number of outcomes is $20^{12}$. The number of ways such that each box gets at most one ball is the same as chosing wich of the twenty boxes get a ball, where the order is important since we distinguish both, balls and boxes. This is $\underbrace{20\cdot 19\cdot \ldots \cdot 9}_{12 \text{ factors}} = \frac{20!}{8!}$. Thus assuming uniform distribution,

$$P = \frac{\frac{20!}{8!}}{20^{12}} = \frac{20!}{8! 20^{12}}$$

Comment: So in general when I have a "something", like a ball, and I am assigning it a place, the total number of outcomes = #of places^(# of things), is that right?

Comment: @user181304 Yes, because you _independently_ go through the things, selecting one of the places each time. In this example:
$$20\cdot20\cdot\ldots\cdot20 = 20^{12}$$
The independence of these choices allowes us to multiply the factors without losing anything.

Answer (score 1):

I've been toiling over a complete understanding of this problem and all of the other possible outcomes where boxes can have more than one ball.

In general, suppose $k$ balls are thrown into $n$ boxes. Let $b_t$ represent the number of boxes containing $t$ balls so that we have $$\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^k b_j=n \quad \text{ and } \quad \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^n j b_j=k.$$ Given $\{b_t\}_{t\geq0}$, let $a_m$ represent the number of balls in box $m$ for a particular realization of this experiment so that $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n a_i=k.$$ It does not matter which specific realization we choose for the $\{a_m\}_{m\geq1}$. I prefer to have $a_1\geq a_2 \geq ... \geq a_n$. In other words, the order of the boxes doesn't matter.

We want to know the probability of $\{b_0, b_1, ... b_k\}$ (i.e. that $b_0$ boxes have no balls, $b_1$ boxes have 1 ball each, $b_2$ boxes have 2 balls each, etc.). The desired probability is

$$P\left(\{b_0, b_1, ... b_k\}\right)=
\frac{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
n\\
b_0, b_1, ... b_k
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
k\\
a_1, a_2, ... a_n
\end{array}
\right)}{n^k}.$$

The question asked in the original post is for $k=12$, $n=20$, $b_0=8$, $b_1=12$, and $b_t=0$ for $1<t\leq 12$. This is from DeGroot and Schervish $\S 1.7$ exercise $\# 7$ (4th ed.). Within the framework outlined above the desired probability is
$$\displaystyle P\left(\{8,12,\underbrace{0,...,0}_{10\text{ zeros}}\}\right)=
\frac{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
20\\
8,12,\underbrace{0,...,0}_{10\text{ zeros}}
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
12\\
\underbrace{1,...,1}_{12\text{ ones}},\underbrace{0,...,0}_{8\text{ zeros}}
\end{array}
\right)}{20^{12}} 
= \frac{\frac{20!}{8!12!}\frac{12!}{1!1!\cdots 1!}}{20^{12}}= \frac{20!}{8!20^{12}}
$$ 
Just as expected from the above answer.

For an illustration, let's experiment by throwing 5 balls into 6 boxes. What is the probability that one box gets 3 balls and 2 boxes get one ball each?

Since 3 boxes get no balls, $b_0=3$, $b_1=2$, $b_2=0$, $b_3=1$, and $b_4=b_5=0$. Let $a_1=3$, $a_2=a_3=1$, and $a_4=a_5=a_6=0$, without loss of generality (we could re-order the boxes any way we please). The desired probability is
$$P\left(\{3,2,0,1,0,0\}\right)=
\frac{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
6\\
3,2,0,1,0,0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
5\\
3,1,1,0,0,0
\end{array}
\right)}{6^5}.$$
Note that the zeros in the multinomial coefficient are redundant, so this simplifies to
$$P\left(\{3,2,0,1,0,0\}\right)=
\frac{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
6\\
3,2,1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
5\\
3,1,1
\end{array}
\right)}{6^5}
=
\frac{\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4}{2}\cdot5\cdot4}{6^5}=\frac{200}{6^4}\approx0.1543.$$
Also, note that the number of balls is allowed to be larger than the number of boxes.

I haven't tried to prove this formula yet, but it has worked for all examples I've tried (running numerical simulations).

Answer (score 0):

Model the situation as mappings from the set $\{1,\dots,12\}$ into the set $\{1, \dots, 20\}$.

The total number of possibilities (mappings) is $20^{12}$.

The requirement amounts  to having an injection. So the number of favourable cases is
$$\frac{20!}{(20-12)!}$$
Thus the probability is $$p=\frac{20!}{8!\,20^{12}}\approx0.0147. $$

Comment: There are more injections. Precisely $\binom{20}{12} \cdot 12!$ thus the probability is as outlined in the other answers.

Comment: Oops! Mixed the binomiial coefficients with the number of arrangements. I'll fix that in a moment. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: How do we get the insight that the question assumes distinguishability of balls and boxes. I mean i get the answer but just this distinguishability part is not clear