# Distributing particles into boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, balls-in-bins

In our homework we had the following problem:

> Let's consider $n$- many particles. Each of them has the probability $\frac{1}{N}$ to land in one of $N$-many numbered boxes, where $N>n$.  We select $n$-many boxes. What is the probability that in each of those $n$ boxes is exactly one particle?
>
> Assume that (like Bose-Einstein statistic) the cases which can be generated by simply swapping the particles are identical. It only matters how many particles are in a box and not which particles.

**My approach:**

It is clear that the elements of the sample space $\Omega$ can be counted by the combinatorial model of "indistinguishable objects and distinguishable boxes" hence we define  $\Omega:=\{\omega\in\mathbb{N}^n\mid1\leq\omega_1\leq\dots\leq \omega_n\leq N\}$, where $|\Omega|={N+n-1\choose n}$.

The problem is that we don't know the probability distribution/the probability of each element of $\Omega$. The information that each particle lands with probability $\frac{1}{N}$ in one box doesn't help. Sure it makes sense to assume that the probability is equally distributed among the elements of $\Omega$ (which would turn this into a pretty easy problem) but this information can't be elicited from the question.

So in my opinion we can't solve this question without any further information on the probability distribution.

Am I missing something? Or do you agree?

Comment: The quoted question can be read as saying that **first** $n$ particles land at random among $N$ boxes, **then** $n$ boxes are selected at random from among the $N$ boxes, and we're asked to find the probability that these selected boxes are found to contain one particle each. This is of course different from the title question.

Comment: @r.e.s. ouhh I totally missed that someone had changed the title which may have lead to confusion. The question should be understand the way you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming** Bose-Einstein statistics, the answer to the quoted question is of course just ${1\over\binom{N+n-1}{n}}$, because whichever might be the selected $n$ boxes, having exactly one particle in each of them corresponds to exactly one of the equally-likely outcomes in the sample space.

---

The issue, it seems to me, is whether assuming something "**like** Bose-Einstein statistics" is the same as assuming Bose-Einstein statistics. (If it is not the same, then I agree the question hasn't provided enough information to be answered.) The second quoted paragraph says

> Assume that (like Bose-Einstein statistic[s]) the cases which can be generated by simply swapping the particles are identical. It only matters how many particles are in a box and not which particles.

Apparently this is intended to specify that Bose-Einstein statistics are to be assumed; but, saying "*like* Bose-Einstein" -- and only mentioning the "indistinguishable particles" part of that model --  doesn't make it very clear that we are to also assume the other essential part of that model, namely that the $\binom{N+n-1}{n}$ outcomes in the sample space are equally-likely.

Also, nothing else in the quoted problem clarifies this issue. In particular, the statement ...

> Each [particle] has the probability 1/N to land in one of N-many numbered boxes

... implies that the particle locations are uniformly distributed among the boxes, although it does *not* imply that these are also mutually *independent*. (So we also cannot assume a sample space of $N^n$ equally-likely outcomes.) In fact, *if we assume this independence, then the $\binom{N+n-1}{n}$ outcomes in the sample space are not equally likely* -- contradicting the Bose-Einstein model.

To see this, just consider the case of $n=2, N=3$, assuming independent locations of the particles:
$$\begin{align}P(\text{both particles land in box$_1$})=\underbrace{P(\text{particle$_1$ lands in box$_1$})}_{1\over 3}\cdot \underbrace{P(\text{particle$_2$ lands in box$_1$})}_{1\over 3}
={1\over 9}\end{align}$$
whereas in the Bose-Einstein model we have
$$P(\text{both particles land in box$_1$})={1\over\binom{3+2-1}{2}}={1\over 6}.$$

---

As an aside, one might wonder: If the particles are allocated one-at-a-time -- and their locations must be *uniformly* **but not independently** distributed among the $N$ boxes -- then how exactly can this be done to produce Bose-Einstein statistics? E.g., by what pseudorandom algorithm can this be simulated?

Such an algorithm is implicit in the following article (p. 1655): Ijiri Y, Simon H A. [Some distributions associated with Bose-Einstein statistics](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC432601/). Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A. 1975;72(5):1654-1657. Namely:

- Allocate the particles one-at-a-time to $N$ boxes numbered $1,...,N,$ by repeatedly applying the following rule, starting with no particles yet allocated:

  - If $r$ particles have been allocated, producing particle counts $(r_k)_{k=1,..,N}$ in the $N$ boxes (so $\sum_{k=1}^Nr_k=r$), then allocate the next particle to box-number $X$, where $X$ is chosen from $\{1,...,N\}$ according to the probability distribution specified by $$P(X=k)={r_k+1\over r+N}\,[k\in\{1,...,N\}].$$

Comment: I've sketched a proof of the above algorithm in my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4447068/16397) to an old MathSE question.